# argument package is of type <class 'dict'> and we were unable to convert to list error in Ansible

Tags: pip, ansible

This is my code -

```
 vars:
    python_version:
      - 3
      - 2

  tasks:
  - block:
    - set_fact:
        yum_name: "{{ 'python' ~ item ~ '-pip.noarch' }}"
      loop: "{{ python_version }}"
      register: yum_name

    - debug:
        var: '{{ yum_name }}'

    - name: install
      yum:
        name: '{{ yum_name }}'
        state: present
      become: yes
```

error -

```
"msg": "argument package is of type <class 'dict'> and we were unable to convert to list: <class 'dict'> cannot be converted to a list"
```

I am installing pip2 and pip3, using these packages -

python2-pip.noarch & python3-pip.noarch

I know I can just type both separately and yum install but I wanted to dynamically put in the version numbers and then install it, rather then having similar packages named twice.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        yum_name: "{{ yum_name|default([]) + ['python' ~ item ~ '-pip.noarch'] }}"
      loop: "{{ python_version }}"
```

gives the list

```yaml
  yum_name:
  - python3-pip.noarch
  - python2-pip.noarch
```

This list can be used in *yum*

```yaml
    - name: install
      yum:
        name: '{{ yum_name }}'
        state: present
      become: yes
```

---

The next option is to create the list in the *vars* section, e.g.

```yaml
  vars:
    python_version:
      - 3
      - 2
    yum_name: "{{ yum_name_str|from_yaml }}"
    yum_name_str: |
      {% for version in python_version %}
      - python{{ version }}-pip.noarch
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: so will I do yum: , name: yum_name , state:present , become: yes ? After doing this yum install with 'yum_name' .. I get   'No package matching 'yum_name' is available'

Comment: [edit] your question and make it [mre] if you have problems. Do not put code into the comments.